# Does the main thread block when using the pthread_join function?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am writing a multithreaded program. The introduction to pthread_join in the linux manual is:
`The pthread_join() function waits for the thread specified by  thread to terminate`.

I'm curious if this sentence means that the main thread and the child thread run separately, but when the child thread ends, the main thread can end.

```
Child1 thread: 0
Child1 thread: 1
...
Child1 thread: 9999
Parent thread: 0
...
Parent thread: 99
```

The result is always that after the child thread ends, the for loop behind the main thread will be executed. Does this mean that `pthread_join` executes the child thread, blocks the main thread, and executes the main thread when the child thread ends?

But when I delete the comments of the following code, that is, create two child-threads, the expected phenomenon does not occur. child-thread 1 and child-thread 2 run crosswise. When the child thread 1 and the child thread 2 are finished, the for loop after the main thread `pthread_join` starts to run.

Can someone explain more clearly how `pthread_join` runs the child thread and the main thread?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "../utils/memory_utils.h"
#include "../utils/cache_utils.h"
#include "../utils/misc_utils.h"


void function(char *str){
   for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){

     printf("%s thread: %d\n", str, i);
   }

}


int main(){
  char *str = "string";
  pthread_t start,start_2;
   if (pthread_create(&start, NULL, (void *)function, "Child1") != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create: trojan");
  }

  // if (pthread_create(&start_2, NULL, (void *)function, "Child2") != 0) {
  //   perror("pthread_create: trojan");
  // }


   pthread_join(start, NULL);
  //  pthread_join(start_2, NULL);


   for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
     printf("Parent thread: %d\n", i);
   }
  
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: *Any* thread invoking `pthread_join` to await the demise of another joinable thread blocks the thread calling `pthread_join`, be it the 'main' thread or otherwise.And  `pthread_join` doesn't "run the child thread"; it waits for it to complete. The child thread is running (as far as you know) as soon as `pthread_create` returns with success. Unrelated, your child thread is not a proper signature for a `pthread`. It should be `void* (*)(void*)`, not `void (*)(char*)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_join()` is fairly simple.  Per [its docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html):

> The `pthread_join()` function waits for the thread specified by
> `thread` to terminate.  If that thread has already terminated, then
> `pthread_join()` returns immediately.

That is, yes, `pthread_join()` blocks the caller when that is necessary and appropriate.  But it has no effect on any threads other than the caller's, not even the one being joined, and the number of currently-running threads is not directly relevant to `pthread_join()`s behavior.

You asked,

> Does this mean that `pthread_join` executes the child thread, blocks the main thread, and executes the main thread when the child thread ends?

No.

Each successful call to `pthread_create()` starts a new thread that runs in parallel with all others in the process.  If the system has multiple execution units, as most now do, then some of those parallel threads are likely to run concurrently on different execution units some of the time.  No matter how many execution units are available, including if there is only one, the threads will share those execution units.

Scheduling execution time for threads is a function of the OS.  No additional function calls are required to make it happen, and in particular, `pthread_join()` has nothing to do with making a thread run.  Its job is to wait for the specified thread to *finish* running, and optionally to provide that thread's return value.  That's all.  And when it completes that task and returns, execution of the thread that performed the `pthread_join()` call continues normally, just as it would upon return from any other function call.

And you asked,

> Can someone explain more clearly how `pthread_join` runs the child thread and the main thread?

`pthread_join()` does not do either of those things, except inasmuch as its return permits the thread that called it to proceed.

When one thread is blocked in `pthread_join()` that has no effect on the execution of other threads.  All running, unblocked threads will execute in parallel, and perhaps concurrently, as already described.  However many that is.  That threads run in parallel is one of their key characteristics.

So yes, if the initial thread starts two others then attempts to join one of them, it is likely that the two additional threads will execute "crosswise".  If you don't want that (at all) then you don't want threads.  If you want to *control* that then that's one of the major functions of synchronization tools such as mutexes and condition variables.